# Class Inheritance Problem

Tags: php

I have A.php and B.php

A.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors",1);
class myClass
{
  function hello()
  {
    return 'hello';
  }  
}
?>
```

B.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors",1);
require_once('/A.php');
$a = new myClass();
testing();

function testing()
{    
    echo $a ->hello();
}
?>
```

B.php inherits A.php ,
if i run B.php,but it show 
"Fatal error: Call to a member function hello() on a non-object."

So the question is simple, how can i correct this ,but "$a = new myClass();" is not inside the function, since in .NET world can do this, i believe PHP also possible.

And one more question is, what is the modify of function in A.php ,if i have not state  private/public/protected?

Comment: This isn't inheritance.  This is an issue with variable scope, file include and method access modifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things I would change here,  I'll explain in a moment.

**A.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors",1);

class myClass
{
  // Here, access modifier.
  public function hello()
  {
    return 'hello';
  }  
}
?>
```

**B.php**

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors",1);

require_once('/A.php');
testing();

function testing()
{   
    // Here, change where variable is defined to place it in scope.
    $a = new myClass();
    echo $a ->hello();
}
?>
```

When no access specifier is given on a method, it defaults to `public`.  However, it is generally better to just declare what you want the method to have.  You will appreciate this if you find yourself actively coding in multiple languages as they will each have a different default.

Right now the variable `$a` is not in the scope of the function testing().  Allow me to rearrange your program and you shall see why.  You could have written it, like so:

**B.php**

```
<?php
function testing()
{       
    echo $a ->hello();
}    

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors",1);

require_once('/A.php');
$a = new myClass();
testing();

?>
```

You see, where `testing()` is now defined, `$a` does not exist.  It hasn't been defined yet.  So it is not inside `testing()`'s scope.  You'll have to either define `$a` inside `testing()` or else pass it in as a parameter.  In my first pass, I changed your code to define `$a` inside `testing()`.  If you will need to use it in multiple functions, then I would suggest changing `testing()` to take it as a parameter.  Like this:

```
function testing(myClass $a) {
    echo $a->hello();
}
```

Then pass it in this way:

```
$a = new myClass();
testing($a);
```

Answer (score 5):

This is not inheritance.  `B.php` merely *includes* `A.php`.  This means all the code in `A.php` becomes available to the execution context of `B.php`.

**Inheritance** is a class relationship

```
class A{}

class B extends A{}
```

Class B can be said to *inherit* from A.  So, a hierarchy has been formed.

Much as we humans inherit traits from our parents, classes inherit properties from *their* parents.  For this reason, it is *very* common to talk about these classes in terms of their place in the hierarchy.  Class A is a *parent* to class B.  Class B is a *child* to class A.

But the actual problem you are having, the source of the error message, is a scope issue.  You create `$a` in the global scope but attempt to access it from within a function's scope, in this case `testing()`.

The best way to solve this is to pass your instances of `myClass` into `testing()`

```
$a = new myClass();
testing( $a );

function testing( $myClassObj )
{    
    echo $myClassObj->hello();
}
```

And to answer your final question - in PHP5 - class members not explicitly declared with an access modifier become implicitly `public`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use $a in the function, you need to either put

```
global $a;
```

as the first line of the function, or access it as `$GLOBALS['a']`

Comment: I would rather he simply declare it inside the function than make it a global and access it through the globals array...

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
function testing()
{   
    global $a;
    echo $a ->hello();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `$a` is not defined in the function. Try using global $a first, and then calling hello().